# Saving all sql queries in a project as a single file in PGAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, github, pgadmin-4

I'm working on a data analysis case study and want to share the code in github.
Is there any way to save all sql queries as a single file in PgAdmin 4 ?

I'm using PostgreSQL and PgAdmin 4.

Answer (score 0):

PgAdmin is a tool to execute the queries and view its result,
but if you need to maintain a github code repository,

you could use a text code editor like **notepad++** or **visual studio code** etc.
This will help you simplify git operations of pull, push commits etc.